# How to listen to when slickgrid size changes?

Tags: javascript, events, slickgrid

I know if the encapsulating div size changes for example via debugger console, then I would have to manually call `grid.resizeCanvas()` for slickgrid to recalculate its size. Is there an event I can subscribe to that would get called whenever resizing happens for the grid?

Answer (score 0):

Could you explain when would the encapsulating div resize? If it just resizes whenever the window itself resizes, you can just put it in the window resize handler.

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    grid.resizeCanvas();
});
```

Comment: I was hoping that I could just bind to an event when `grid.resizeCanvas ()`is called. Is there such an event?